# Better way to store the address and value of a pointer, and reuse that same pointer variable without using dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++

Sorry if this question is already answered somewhere else, but I've been searching for a couple days and haven't been able to find exactly what I'm looking for.

I was wondering what a safer/cleaner way is to store a pointer (keep the address and value the same and store in some container) and reuse that same pointer variable.

Currently, I'm just using dynamic memory allocation and manually deleting it later on, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this (I'll elaborate more after the code, since it may be easier to understand what I'm asking for then).

I attached some sample code below with what I'm talking about, and how I am currently doing it (please bear with me on any glaring mistakes, I'm still learning C++):

```
struct MyStruct{
    double* arr;
    MyStruct* parent_struct;
};


MyStruct* first_struct = new MyStruct;
first_struct->arr = some_array;
first_struct->parent_struct = nullptr;

std::vector<MyStruct*>* my_vector = new std::vector<MyStruct*>();
my_vector->push_back(first_struct);

double* temp_array;
MyStruct* temp_struct;
MyStruct* previous_struct;

for (i=0; i<num_iterations; i++){
    temp_array = new double[sizeofarray];
    assign_some_values(temp_array);
    assign_struct_some_values(previous_struct);

    if (some_condition(temp_array)){
       temp_struct = new MyStruct;
       temp_struct->arr = temp_array;
       temp_struct->parent_struct = previous_struct;
       my_vector->push_back(temp_struct);
    } else{
        delete [] temp_array;
    }
}
... use values in my_vector ...
for (j=0; j<my_vector.size(); j++){
    delete [] (*my_vector)[j]->arr;
    delete (*my_vector)[j];
}
delete my_vector;
```

The main thing is, what alternative to the dynamically allocated arrays/structures can I use?

Please keep in mind that I would like to try to keep the address and values the same once they are added to `my_vector`, if at all possible (due to some requirements with the code I'm using). I feel like there is a much better way to do this without dynamic memory allocation, or so many pointers (like using smart pointers, `std::array`, etc), but I haven't been able to properly get any of the other methods to work.

When I try using smart pointers, I can't seem to get the custom deleter to work properly for the structures.

And when using a container (like `std::vector`) for the `arr` variables instead of `double*`, they keep getting deallocated (or I'm accidentally changing the address/values somehow) before the `for` loop is finished.

Comment: If you have a problem with `std::vector`, then one of the better options is to ask a question about your problem with `std::vector`; and one of the worse options is to go back to `new` and raw pointers and ask questions about that.

Comment: what custom deleter do you need here?!

Comment: `struct MyStruct{ double* arr; MyStruct* parent_struct;};` -- That entire code you have is more or less `typedef std::list<std::vector<double>> MyStruct;`.  All of that code you have now to add a vector to a list is handled by `std::list`.

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcKenzie, I'll take a look at that!